# Google Compute Engine snapshots not displaying actual space used

Tags: disk, snapshot, google-compute-engine

If I take a snapshot of a persistent disk, then try to see get information about the snapshot in gcutil, the data is always incomplete.  I need to see this data since snapshots are differential.:

```
server$ gcutil getsnapshot snapshot-3
+----------------------+-----------------------------------+
| name                 | snapshot-3                        |
| description          |                                   |
| creation-time        | 2014-07-30T06:52:56.223-07:00     |
| status               | READY                             |
| disk-size-gb         | 200                               |
| storage-bytes        |                                   |
| storage-bytes-status |                                   |
| source-disk          | us-central1-a/disks/app-db-1-data |
+----------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to determine what this snapshot is actually occupying? gcutil and the web UI are the only resources I know of, and they are both not displaying this information.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it's a bug, known by google developers. They are working on that....